# Custom keyboard layouts: adding a character for which no keysym is defined

Tags: keyboard-layout, xkb, unicode-entry

A couple of years ago, I followed the [custom keyboard layout howto](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Howto%3a%20Custom%20keyboard%20layout%20definitions), and have been in dvorak+bilingual+typographic bliss ever since.

I’d now like to add the thin non-breaking space (`U+202F`) as one of my alternate keys in my arsenal (which precedes colons and question marks when writing in French), but it appears that no `keysym` is defined for this character in `/usr/include/X11/keysymdef.h`, so it’s not clear to me how to go about adding it.

Any thoughts? Is there some way I can simply provide the Unicode number in the layout definition file? Or is there a way to define a new `keysym`?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 8):

Yeah, it is possible to use the Unicode code directly in xkb keyboard layout definition files in `/usr/share/X11/xkb/symbols/` or to use with `keysym` using this format `U####` or `0x100####`.

Example:

```
key <AD04> { [        r, R,           U200F,        U200E           ] };
```

Or to define new keysym:

```
xmodmap -e "keysym RLM = U200F"
```

For permanent keysym, add to  `~/.xmodmap` file:

```
keysym RLM = U200F
```

References:

- [Custom xkb layout in which one key creates two Unicode code points](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/43073/custom-xkb-layout-in-which-one-key-creates-two-unicode-code-points)
- [FOSS Localization/Annex B: Technical Aspects](https://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/FOSS_Localization/Annex_B%3a_Technical_Aspects)
- [Creating and Compiling Custom Keymaps for Linux](http://h20565.www2.hp.com/portal/site/hpsc/template.BINARYPORTLET/public/kb/docDisplay/resource.process/?spf_p.tpst=kbDocDisplay_ws_BI&spf_p.rid_kbDocDisplay=docDisplayResURL&javax.portlet.begCacheTok=com.vignette.cachetoken&spf_p.rst_kbDocDisplay=wsrp-resourceState=docId%253Demr_na-c01605075-3%257CdocLocale%253D&javax.portlet.endCacheTok=com.vignette.cachetoken)