# Configuring keyboard hotkeys with same scancodes and different keysyms

Tags: keyboard, shortcut-keys, xmodmap, xkb, keycodes

I have a bluetooth keyboard [Samsung bkb10](http://www.samsung.com/us/support/owners/product/BKB-10USWEGXAR). It is keyboard for andoind mainly, so it does not have alt, super(winkey), f1-f12, menu, but has lots of hotkeys(most of them work nice under linux). But some hotkeys are not working, and I want to make thems to behave as alt, f1-f12, menu. Also i want hotkeys functions too, so i would love to make smth like Fn button for hotkeys. Well, that is all i want. At least i need alt,super,menu and f1-f12, could not imagine it is so hard without them under linux. 
So, i was trying to use keytouch - no luck.
It is able to read correct keysym, but keytouch-editor saves only part of it into its keyboard files, and it appears that needed keys are same for keytouch too. Anyway i did not see it works for me at all, even with with many keys acting the same way. Right now keys that i want to make as Alt, super, menu, do not work at all, have same scancodes, but have different keysyms:

`xev`  shows same thing for some hotkeys, that do not work :

```
KeyRelease event, serial 39, synthetic NO, window 0x5400001,
root 0xf5, subw 0x0, time 12647284, (224,225), root:(224,253),
state 0x0, keycode 248 (keysym 0x0, NoSymbol), same_screen YES,
XLookupString gives 0 bytes: 
XFilterEvent returns: False
```

But `kacpimon` can recognize their keysyms and that they are different keys:

```
Input Layer:  Type: 4  Code: 4  Value: 787205
Input Layer:  Type: 1  Code: 240  Value: 0
Input Layer:  Sync
Input Layer:  Type: 4  Code: 4  Value: 787207
Input Layer:  Type: 1  Code: 240  Value: 1
Input Layer:  Sync
```

Same as `getscancodes`:

```
787205 (0xc0305)
787205 (0xc0305)
787207 (0xc0307)
787207 (0xc0307)
```

`sudo evtest /dev/input/evt14` output for same keys:

```
Event: time 1457614378.384393, type 4 (EV_MSC), code 4 (MSC_SCAN), value c0305
Event: time 1457614378.384393, type 1 (EV_KEY), code 240 (KEY_UNKNOWN), value 1
Event: time 1457614378.384393, -------------- SYN_REPORT ------------
Event: time 1457614378.384420, type 4 (EV_MSC), code 4 (MSC_SCAN), value c0305
Event: time 1457614378.384420, type 1 (EV_KEY), code 240 (KEY_UNKNOWN), value 0
Event: time 1457614378.384420, -------------- SYN_REPORT ------------
Event: time 1457614378.681877, type 4 (EV_MSC), code 4 (MSC_SCAN), value c0307
Event: time 1457614378.681877, type 1 (EV_KEY), code 240 (KEY_UNKNOWN), value 1
Event: time 1457614378.681877, -------------- SYN_REPORT ------------
Event: time 1457614378.775600, type 4 (EV_MSC), code 4 (MSC_SCAN), value c0307
Event: time 1457614378.775600, type 1 (EV_KEY), code 240 (KEY_UNKNOWN), value 0
Event: time 1457614378.775600, -------------- SYN_REPORT ------------
```

As you can see scancodes are same even in `kacpimon`, but keysyms are different in `kacpimon`, `getscancode`, `evtest` for every single key, but not for `xev` and other tools. 
Also i think that getscancodes actually is showing keysyms, but not scancodes for them.
I know that xmodmap is old and i should not use, and that i should xkb. I was able to find some answer that could help me, if i wasn't noob - [Custom keyboard layouts: adding a character for which no keysym is defined](https://askubuntu.com/questions/429946/custom-keyboard-layouts-adding-a-character-for-which-no-keysym-is-defined)
Also that link might be usefull but it is outdated, so i cannot check it-[Don't use showkey or xev -- use udev and evtest instead.](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/130762/160491)

But i cannot do it with xkb or xmodmap, i just cannot understand how. Please help me, working on it for 3 full days and still did not find any solution... Thank you very much!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, solution was found here- [Make the zoom slider of Microsoft Natural Ergonomic Keyboard 4000 and 7000 scroll up and down, in 14.04 (Trusty)](https://askubuntu.com/questions/471802/make-the-zoom-slider-of-microsoft-natural-ergonomic-keyboard-4000-and-7000-scrol)
Read last comment. 
It turned out, that evtest is really powerful, and it can show scancodes too. 
Read /lib/udev/hwdb.d/60-keyboard.hwdb very carefull, i had to read it 100 times to make it work. 
If you need to transorm your hex to 4 digit hex i used this - http://www.binaryhexconverter.com/hex-to-decimal-converter